# Convert Speech To Text Android Aplication

Tags: android

I am working on speech to text Android application and I am stuck on a problem. Ii want that if the user stops to talking, the application should not stop to taking input, it should continue running state until the time not ends it should take speech as an input.

My Code:
       @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (speech != null) {
        speech.destroy();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "destroy");
    }

}

@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Start On ready",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    speech.startListening(i);

}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressBar.setMax(20);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Stop On ready",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Start On begining",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    speech.startListening(i);
    CountDownTimer cd=  new CountDownTimer(180000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //do nothing, just let it tick

            txt4.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000));

             /*  if(millisUntilFinished/1000==24)
                {
                    speech.stopListening();
                    speech.startListening(i);
                }
                else if(millisUntilFinished/1000==18 )
               {
                   speech.stopListening();
                   speech.startListening(i);
               }
                else if(millisUntilFinished/1000==12)
               {
                   speech.stopListening();
                   speech.startListening(i);
               }
                else if(millisUntilFinished/1000==6)
               {
                   speech.stopListening();
                   speech.startListening(i);
               }
                else if(millisUntilFinished/1000==1)
                {
                    speech.stopListening();
                    speech.stopListening();
                }*/

        }
        public void onFinish() {
            txt4.setText("Stop On begining");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Stop On begining",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              speech.stopListening();
            // speech.startListening(i);
        }
    };
    cd.start();
}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRmsChanged: " + rmsdB);
    progressBar.setProgress((int) rmsdB);
}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBufferReceived: " + buffer);
}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
    scoree();
}

@Override
public void onError(int error) {

    String errorMessage = getErrorText(error);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FAILED " + errorMessage);
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
   txt.setText(errorMessage);
  //  toggleButton.setChecked(false);
}


@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    ArrayList<String> thingsYouSaid = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    one=txt.getText().toString();
    txt1.setText(thingsYouSaid.get(0));
    two=txt1.getText().toString();
    am  = two.split(" ");
    for(k=0;k<arr.length;k++) {
        n=k;
        for (int i = 0; i < am.length; i++)
        {
            p=i;
            flag1=1;

            if (flag==0 && arr[k].equals(am[i]) ) {
                my[i]=k;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "   my[i]"+   my[i] , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                SpannableString spn = new SpannableString(arr[k]);
                spn.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, spn.length(), 0);
                txt.setText(spn);
                Count=Count+1;
                flag=1;
            }
            else if(flag1==1 && arr[k].equals(am[i])) {
                my[i]=k;
                SpannableString spn1 = new SpannableString(" " + arr[k]);
                spn1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, spn1.length(), 0);
                txt.append(spn1);
                Count=Count+1;
            }
            else if(!arr[k].equals(am[i]))
            {

                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Say Correct word" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                flag2=1;
            }
        }
    }
    for(k=0;k<arr.length;k++) {
        for (a=0; a<arr.length ; a++) {
            if (my[k]!=a && a==k) {
                SpannableString spn2 = new SpannableString(" " + arr[k]);
                spn2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, spn2.length(), 0);
                txt.append(spn2);

            }
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPartialResults");
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEvent");
}
public  String getErrorText(int errorCode) {
    String message;
    switch (errorCode) {
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
            message = "Audio recording error";
        //    scoree();
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
            message = "Client side error";
          //  scoree();
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
            message = "Insufficient permissions";
          //  scoree();
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
            message = "Network error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
            message = "Network timeout";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
            message = "No match";
          //  scoree();
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
            message = "RecognitionService busy";
         //   scoree();
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
            message = "error from server";
         //   scoree();
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
            message = "No speech input";
         //   scoree();
            break;
        default:
            message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
         //   scoree();
            break;
    }
    return message;
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: How does the user indicate that the application should stop taking input? Are you using a speech-to-text API? How do you turn on/off the microphone?

Comment: m using timer there and i just want  that my application should take input until the timer does not end and if user stop to speak some thing but application should be able to take input until it does not complete it's time